# How to add "ON UPDATE" to column definition in prisma schema?

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I want to create column with the following definition

```
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE now(),
```

But when I type in `schema.prisma`

```
  updated_at             DateTime               @updatedAt @db.DateTime(0)
```

Then I obtains table with column:

```
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
```

How to add `ON UPDATE now()` to this column using prisma? I use MySQL/MariaDB.

---

References:

Connected problem

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5799#issuecomment-894631317

Article about ON UPDATE

https://medium.com/@bengarvey/use-an-updated-at-column-in-your-mysql-table-and-make-it-update-automatically-6bf010873e6a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [client reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#updatedat) it seems that the client itself is responsible for providing the updated at DATETIME value instead of the way you're wanting it (to be done in the DB server).

If you really need the table/column definition to be exactly as you want, I would suggest creating or modifying the table directly in SQL and then using [introspect](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/introspection) to import the definition in your schema.

You could even add the definitions to your prisma migration files as these are just plain sql files. How to do this can be found in the [Customizing Migrations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/customizing-migrations) article

Comment: The customizing migrations link that you provided was the solution for me